# Append Text at exact location in text

Tags: c#

I was looking to append text to a exact location in a text file.  I have used `StreamReader` to find the text in the file I am looking for.  I thought about using `StreamWriter` but that obviously doesn't make sense.  I was hoping to find some "append" method in some class somewhere that would help me do this but with now success. Or is there a better way to do this than to use StreamReader?

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("VAR_GLOBAL CONSTANT"))
                {
                    //append text before this variable
                    // e.g.  (*VAR_GLOBAL CONSTANT 
                    // append the (*  before VAR_GLOBAL CONSTANT
                }
                if (line.Contains("END_VAR"))
                {
                    //append text after this variable
                    // e.g.   END_VAR*)
                    // append the *) after END_VAR
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: There is no way to "grow" a file from a point other than the end.  1. seek to your insert point.  2.  read the rest of the file from that point on into a buffer or temp file.  3.  Insert the new text at point (1).  4.  Append the buffer after the inserted text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to read the file contents into a string, update the contents locally, and then write it back to the file again. This probably isn't very feasible for really large files, especially if the appending is done at the end, but it's a start:

```
var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";

var appendBeforeDelim = "VAR_GLOBAL CONSTANT";
var appendAfterDelim = "END_VAR";

var appendBeforeText = "Append this string before some text";
var appendAfterText = "Append this string after some text";

var newFileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath)
    .Replace(appendBeforeDelim, $"{appendBeforeText}{appendBeforeDelim}")
    .Replace(appendAfterDelim, $"{appendAfterDelim}{appendAfterText}");

File.WriteAllText(filePath, newFileContents);
```